# Syntax error with print()

Tags: python, syntax-error

Our lecturer gave us some code to help us with an assignment and when I try to run it I get a syntax error. I haven't touched the code at all and it's meant to run without us having to change anything. This is half the code that we were given:

```
class Flusher(MessageProc):
        def main(self):
            super().main()
            print('before start message')
            self.receive(
                Message(
                    'start',
                    action=self.flush))
            print('after start message')
            self.receive(
                Message(
                    ANY,
                    action=lambda data:print('The first thing in the queue after the flush is', data)))
        def flush(self, *args):
            self.receive(
                Message(
                    ANY,
                    action=self.flush), # recursively call the flush method
                TimeOut(
                    0,
                    action=lambda: None)) # when no more messages return
```

And the line that throws the exception is:

```
action=lambda data:print('The first thing in the queue after the flush is', data)
```

This is my first time using Python so please can someone explain what's wrong and what I should do to fix it.

EDIT: The error trace is:

```
File "./demo_timeout.py", line 18
    action=lambda data:print('The first thing in the queue after the flush is' + data)))
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Post the full error trace...

Comment: Are you on Python 2, or 3? Are you sure?

Comment: @user2357112 I'm using python 3

Comment: The evidence strongly suggests you're mistaken about that.

Comment: So, you think I'm using python 2?

Comment: Well, do you know how I can fix the error?

Comment: Figure out why you're on Python 2 and get on Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

That code is Python 3, and you're attempting to run it using Python 2. If you instead run it in Python 3, you should be good.

How you go about switching to 3 depends entirely on your execution environment, but there's a decent chance you already have a command available called `python3`; if so, you should use that instead of `python` to run the supplied code.

If you don't already have a `python3`, then you need to install it, however you go about installing software on your system.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful